# why there are more strings in python np array output?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm confused as to why the following code answer is:

```
import numpy as np
dt=[('name','S16'),('grad',int),('cpg',float)]
val=[("Ahmadmm",2008,12),('ali',2010,12.2),('mitra',505,15.15)]
arr=np.array(val,dtype=dt)
print(arr)

output:  [(b'Ahmadmm', 2008, 12.  ) (b'ali', 2010, 12.2 ) (b'mitra',  505, 15.15)]
```

Why there is a 'b' before each string?

Comment: This question have to be reopened — the OP didn't ask ”**What** does the 'b' character do in front of a string literal?” but **why** there it is. He obviously wants the string output instead of the bytes one, and not an explanation of the 'b'.

Comment: Instead of your `('name','S16')` use `('name', ' U16')`. **S** mean the string datatype, **U** is the Unicode one. — Then the output will be `[('Ahmadmm', 2008, 12.  ) ('ali', 2010, 12.2 ) ('mitra',  505, 15.15)]`

Answer (score 1):

I think this post answers your question: [What does the 'b' character do in front of a string literal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269765/what-does-the-b-character-do-in-front-of-a-string-literal). The 'b' character is basically indicating a byte literal.

Comment: How can it be closed?

Answer (score 1):

As [NPE](https://stackoverflow.com/users/367273/npe) stated in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269765/what-does-the-b-character-do-in-front-of-a-string-literal), to quote the [Python 2.x documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals):

> A prefix of 'b' or 'B' is ignored in Python 2; it indicates that the literal should become a bytes literal in Python 3 (e.g. when code is automatically converted with 2to3). A 'u' or 'b' prefix may be followed by an 'r' prefix.

The [Python 3 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals) states:

> Bytes literals are always prefixed with 'b' or 'B'; they produce an instance of the bytes type instead of the str type. They may only contain ASCII characters; bytes with a numeric value of 128 or greater must be expressed with escapes.